# Binary encoding (similar to one-hot encoding) but where multiple values are allowed in a single column and row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have data with IDs and three possible labels in a dataframe such that:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|        ID         | TYPE  |
+-------------------+-------+
| Lord of the Rings | Movie |
| Lord of the Rings | Book  |
| Lord of the Rings | Game  |
| Alien             | Movie |
| Alien             | Game  |
| Fight Club        | Book  |
| Fight Club        | Movie |
| Scar Face         | Movie |
| God of War        | Game  |
| Tomb Raider       | Movie |
| Tomb Raider       | Game  |
| Borderlands       | Game  |
| Ulysses           | Book  |
+-------------------+-------+
```

What I want to do is essentially one-hot encoding this data so that I add three columns `Movie`, `Book`, `Game` that are binary encoded to show whether or not that type is true or false for each ID. With this data, however, it will not take in to account duplicates. For example, were I to use `pd.get_dummies`, I would end up with

```
+-------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
|        ID         | TYPE  | Movie | Game | Book |
+-------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
| Lord of the Rings | Movie |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| Lord of the Rings | Book  |     0 |    0 |    1 |
| Lord of the Rings | Game  |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Alien             | Movie |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| Alien             | Game  |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Fight Club        | Book  |     0 |    0 |    1 |
| Fight Club        | Movie |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| Scar Face         | Movie |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| God of War        | Game  |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Tomb Raider       | Movie |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| Tomb Raider       | Game  |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Borderlands       | Game  |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Ulysses           | Book  |     0 |    0 |    1 |
+-------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

Which, as expected, gives a new row for each record. So my question is, can I make this data into

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+------+------+
|        ID         |       TYPE        | Movie | Game | Book |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+------+------+
| Lord of the Rings | [Movie,Game,Book] |     1 |    1 |    1 |
| Alien             | [Movie,Game]      |     1 |    1 |    0 |
| Fight Club        | [Movie,Book]      |     1 |    0 |    1 |
| Scar Face         | [Movie]           |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| God of War        | [Game]            |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Tomb Raider       | [Movie,Game]      |     1 |    1 |    0 |
| Borderlands       | [Game]            |     0 |    1 |    0 |
| Ulysses           | [Book]            |     0 |    0 |    1 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+------+------+
```

without completely transforming my data? Basically, I want to find all the duplicate entries in ID and join them together so that all the types for a given unique ID are in one place (ideally in a list in a single record), and then one-hot encode it in a way that I can see all the true or false values for `TYPE` in one row, aligned with the (now) unique ID.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is usually "yes" -- you're using a general-purpose language on a general-purpose computer, so you have full Turing potential.  The implied question behind this, "how do I do it?" is an open-ended, individualized tutorial, which is *seriously* off-topic for Stack Overflow -- please re-take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That said ... group the rows by ID.  Then simply "OR" the binary columns (don't merely add, in case you have duplicates).  Making a list of the grouped TYPE data is similarly straightforward.

Comment: @Prune I was trying to ask a specific question, but perhaps it didn't come across that way. Do you have any suggestions to make this question better such that it does not get down voted?

Comment: When the manipulation is straightforward, we expect you to show your coding attempt.  A search for "PANDAS merge rows" would bring you plenty of starting points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
(pd.concat( (pd.get_dummies(df['Type']), df), axis=1, sort=False)
   .groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'TYPE': list, 'Movie':'sum', 'Game':'sum', 'Book':'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
                  ID                 TYPE  Movie  Game  Book
0  Lord of the Rings  [Movie, Book, Game]      1     1     1
1              Alien        [Movie, Game]      1     1     0
2         Fight Club        [Book, Movie]      1     0     1
3          Scar Face              [Movie]      1     0     0
4         God of War               [Game]      0     1     0
5        Tomb Raider        [Movie, Game]      1     1     0
6        Borderlands               [Game]      0     1     0
7            Ulysses               [Book]      0     0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_dummies` after `groupby()` and `str.join()`:

```
final=df.groupby('ID',sort=False).agg(list)
final.assign(**final['TYPE'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()).reset_index()
```

---

```
                  ID                 TYPE  Book  Game  Movie
0  Lord of the Rings  [Movie, Book, Game]     1     1      1
1              Alien        [Movie, Game]     0     1      1
2         Fight Club        [Book, Movie]     1     0      1
3          Scar Face              [Movie]     0     0      1
4         God of War               [Game]     0     1      0
5        Tomb Raider        [Movie, Game]     0     1      1
6        Borderlands               [Game]     0     1      0
7            Ulysses               [Book]     1     0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `MultiLableBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

final = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = mlb.fit_transform(final.TYPE)
final.assign(**dict(zip(mlb.classes_, a.T)))

                  ID                 TYPE  Book  Game  Movie
0  Lord of the Rings  [Movie, Book, Game]     1     1      1
1              Alien        [Movie, Game]     0     1      1
2         Fight Club        [Book, Movie]     1     0      1
3          Scar Face              [Movie]     0     0      1
4         God of War               [Game]     0     1      0
5        Tomb Raider        [Movie, Game]     0     1      1
6        Borderlands               [Game]     0     1      0
7            Ulysses               [Book]     1     0      0
```

---

#### `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('ID', sort=False).pipe(
    lambda g: g.agg(list).join(g.TYPE.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0))
).reset_index()
```